# string prefixes and escape character in Python

Tags: python, regex

Need help in interpreting string prefixes and escape character. I found this when I was learning about the arguments of `re.compile()` commands below.

```
a = re.compile(r'^([a-z]|_)*$')
b = re.compile(r'^([a-z]|_)*:([a-z]|_)*$')
c = re.compile(r'[=\+/&<>;\'"\?%#$@\,\. \t\r\n]')
```

1. What is the meaning of `r`?
2. What is the meaning of `\'`, `\?`, `\,` and `\.`?
3. What is the meaning of `\t\r\n` ?

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but your questions have nothing to do with `re.compile()`, so its no wonder the docs you looked at didn't help. You were looking in the wrong place. You are asking about [string prefixes](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) and [escape characters](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

Comment: Ah yes.. sorry.. editing the title..

Comment: explained in the doc https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: Please further edit as appropriate. thank you!

Comment: r is raw format. \' \+ etc is going to treat them as the same characters and nothing special.
\t tab \r carriage return \n new line characters

Comment: Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the meaning of r?

This is the **raw** prefix for a string literal. Essentially it prevents normal escaping from occurring, leaving in backslashes. A more in depth explanation was given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2081708/416500

> What is the meaning of \', \?, \, and .?

These are **regex** specific characters that are escaped by the backslashes. The `\?` tells it to look for a literal `?`, the `\,` tells it to look for a literal `,` and the `\.` tells it to look for a literal `.`.

> What is the meaning of \t\r\n ?

`\t` is the tab character, `\r` is a carriage return, and `\n` is the newline character. These all render as whitespace in most programs, but are stored differently.

A handy tool for breaking down regex patterns I use a lot is [Regex Pal](http://www.regexpal.com) (no affiliation) which lets you hover over parts of the regex to see how it is compiled.